# How can I efficiently read small sections from TcpStream?

Tags: performance, rust, tcp

I'm writing an application that will communicate with another service via a TCP connection.

Does it matter, performance-wise, whether I pull the data off of the [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) all at once or will reading individual sections at a time be equally as performant? Compare:

```
fn read_byte_by_byte() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:3001").unwrap();

    let mut endian = [0; 1];
    let mut protocol = [0; 1];
    let mut msg_length = [0; 4];

    stream.read(&mut endian).unwrap();
    stream.read(&mut protocol).unwrap();
    stream.read(&mut [0; 2]).unwrap(); // throw away two padding bytes
    stream.read(&mut msg_length).unwrap();
}
```

```
fn read_in_bulk() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:3001").unwrap();

    let mut full_msg = [0; 8];
    stream.read(&mut full_msg).unwrap();
}
```

Are they equivalent? Or will the former perform worse?

Comment: Note: You should use [`.read_exact(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) in cases like this because [`.read(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) may read *less* than the provided buffer size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in the documentation of [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html):

> The `BufReader<R>` struct adds buffering to any reader.
>
> It can be excessively inefficient to work directly with a `Read`
> instance. For example, every call to `read` on `TcpStream` results in a
> system call. A `BufReader<R>` performs large, infrequent reads on the
> underlying `Read` and maintains an in-memory buffer of the results.
>
> `BufReader<R>` can improve the speed of programs that make small and
> repeated read calls to the same file or network socket. It does not
> help when reading very large amounts at once, or reading just one or a
> few times. It also provides no advantage when reading from a source
> that is already in memory, like a `Vec<u8>`.

So yes, individual byte-by-byte read calls to `TcpStream` is not as performant as reading in bulk, so wrap your `TcpStream` with a `BufReader`, and then you can read it however you want, without significant penalties on performance.